# Pictures not shown when opened in Windows 8.1 (Acer Aspire E5-551G)

Tags: windows-8.1, acer-aspire, pictures

I've got a new Acer Aspire E5-551G withput operating system.
So I installed a fresh version of Windows 8.1 and installed Acers drivers for 64 Bit Win 8.1. But I have a problem seeing pictures. The thumbnail preview works fine but after opening the pictures with windows standard tools I don't see anything. On other platforms (another Win 8.1 pc / android) the pictures are fine.
If you need more information I will try to provide it.
Thanks so far and kind regards.

Comment: What format are the images? Have you tried any third party image viewers? Is Windows updated fully?

Comment: These are all .jpg files. I installed IrfanView as third party tool and it seems to work. Do you know how to get standard app from windows working? Or do you have a clue what the problem might be? Additionally I saw that some thumbnails are black too.

Comment: What's the standard app - Photo Viewer? (Been so long since I ever touched the in-built Windows image viewer that I've forgotten. :) If the *same* images open up fine in Photo Viewer on another Win8.1 PC, ensure your system is up to date. Since it's standard JPG the Camera Codec Pack shouldn't be required, but nevertheless check if it's installed on the other system.

Comment: The built-in app is called "photos" and after updating windows it still does not work.

Comment: Ah, you're talking about the Metro app. Is there an update for it in the Store? Otherwise I'm all out of ideas as to why it would behave differently on multiple PCs.